# Unexpected behavior of JAX jax.lax.switch

Tags: jax

i'm seeing an unexpected behavior in jax.lax.switch.

```
def fun_a():
    print('a')
    
def fun_b():
    print('b')
    
def fun_c():
    print('c')

functions_list=[fun_a,fun_b,fun_c]
```

and then calling

```
jax.lax.switch(0,functions_list)
```

returns

```
a
b
c
```

I would expect to see only "a" printed.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior given the way the JAX compiler works: it expects [Pure functions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions), and your functions are not pure because printing is a side-effect.

If you want printing that behaves as expected within transformed JAX functions, you can use `jax.debug.print`. For example:

```py
import jax

def fun_a():
    jax.debug.print('a')
    
def fun_b():
    jax.debug.print('b')
    
def fun_c():
    jax.debug.print('c')

functions_list=[fun_a,fun_b,fun_c]
jax.lax.switch(0,functions_list)
```

Output:

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because printing is a side effect and you may have unexpected errors by switch it. You have more information in [Jax FAQ](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) with an example where print fails a `jax.grad`.
In your case your functions should return the values you want to print. However the strings are not valid jax type and only numerical values are supported by switch. For instance you can try something like:

```py
def fun_a():
    return ord('a')  # convert 'a' to int (= 97)


def fun_b():
    return ord('b')


def fun_c():
    return ord('c')


functions_list = [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c]
out = jax.lax.switch(0, functions_list)

print(chr(out))  # 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If functions listed need argument you can do that like this by filling operand argument of **lax.switch**

```
import jax

def fun_a(x):
    return x * 2

def fun_b(x):
    return x + 3

def fun_c(x):
    return x ** 2

functions_list=[fun_a,fun_b,fun_c]

chosen_function = jax.lax.switch(0, functions_list, 5)
print(chosen_function)
```